# Localized launch images when changing AppleLanguage in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsuserdefaults

I read a post recently about localized launch images, and I got that to work. The next step was to implement an option in the app that changes the language.

Some posts has described the following method:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"se", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

As far as I understand, it works...

Another approach to the language topic was to implement a functionality that makes it possible to change language at runtime. Instead of using the NSLocalizedString function, I used a function called AMLocalizedString. Search the web for LocalizationSystem.h and .m for more info.

As the other method, this works really good as well.

Now to my small problem.

When the user changes the app language from within the app, all text in the app are changed accordingly. But the launch image remains according to the phones language setting if it is closed and restarted.

Does anyone have any idea? When I was running the app in debug mode, it felt like the launch image is shown before the routine "main" is invoked. That might be the case... and something tricky to deal with...

Thanks for all efforts...

/Henrik

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943659/setting-default-language-for-iphone-app-on-first-run (not the one the user chooses, but the second one.)

Answer (score 1):

The display of the launch image is handled by the OS, not your app, so you won't be able to use code in your app to change it. It will only respond to the device language setting.

Comment: i guess that you have a point there. However, I was hoping that there were some settings for this, in the same way as there are settings for changing the language in the app.