# How to pass environment variables in runtime for an Appstore build?

Tags: ios, environment-variables, ios9

Xcode allows you send environment variables when you are running an app for debugging purposes. Is it possible for Appstore build that I submit to do the same? I would like the environment variables to be passed when user runs the app.

I notice in Build settings for a target there is a way to set the Environment plist. Can this be used for that purpose?

[image]

Comment: Just make sure they are included in the `Release` build configuration. If you mean dynamic values, in this case you should think to build something by using your backend or firebase for a realtime feature.

Comment: What is you goal? Environment variables are not going to be set when the app is tested by Apple. Environment variables are not going to be set when a user downloads and installs your app on their device.

Comment: I am trying to set AppleLanguages to force my targets to run in different language - http://nshipster.com/launch-arguments-and-environment-variables/.  Would rather not put the code that sets AppleLanguages in main.m.

Comment: This isn't possible. You have no access to the environment Springboard sets up for you. Generally this is done by just shipping the language you want and not localizing into the language you don't (and/or configuring this in Info.plist to not include localizations you don't want), but alternately, the `main.m` settings (I assume you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943659/setting-default-language-for-iphone-app-on-first-run) are how you would approach it.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you please explain? Why aren't environment variables going to be set? If you specified some env. var. for Release, and AppStore's build uses your scheme, then does it read "Arguments Passed on Launch" and "Environment Variables" sections?

Comment: Those arguments only apply when run from Xcode.